Facing ServerSelectionTimeOutError while using Dataflow to load to MongoDb
I have written a simple python code in my dataflow job to load from Bigquery to MongoDb. However when i am loading 100-10k records the dataflow completes successfully. If i am trying to load more than 10k records the dataflow fails with below error:
% (self._error_message(selector), timeout, self.description)
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No primary available for writes, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 66a061b659d06dd8af8c02d2
Installed Packages:
pymongo==3.6.1
dnspython
pymongo[srv]
bson
Any inputs on this error or how to resolve it.
Tried suggestions from Stackoverflow or other sources. Still facing similar error
